# How to download a file from a non static link using .bat script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to download the Total counts by date for all King County excel file using a script that will be run later on using task manager. I am stuck due to the link not being static and its naming convention will most likely change in the next few months.

Here's the code that I've written so far:

```
@echo off
::Script to download COVID-19 Data
echo "Downloading Total counts by date for all King County"
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://www.kingcounty.gov/depts/health/covid-19/data/~/media/depts/health/communicable-diseases/documents/C19/data/covid-data-daily-counts-sept-14.ashx -Outfile CovidData.xlsx
echo "Download has been successful!"
cls
pause
```

I was wondering if there's a way to add a wild card like "*" in the invoke-webrequest to ignore the "sept-14" part of the link.

Link: https://www.kingcounty.gov/depts/health/covid-19/data/daily-summary.aspx

Link that needs a script to auto download with task manager (Total counts by date for all King County): [https://www.kingcounty.gov/depts/health/covid-19/data/~/media/depts/health/communicable-diseases/documents/C19/data/covid-data-daily-counts-sept-14.ashx](https://www.kingcounty.gov/depts/health/covid-19/data/%7E/media/depts/health/communicable-diseases/documents/C19/data/covid-data-daily-counts-sept-14.ashx)

Comment: Powershell is capable of generating a date for whatever day, and in whichever format you require. I would suggest therefore that you take  look at some powershell code for doing so, and incorporate it into your code. You may also need to look into creating a switch statement for the month, if each is not abbreviated using the standard, month shortnames, (`MMM`, _UFormat_ `%b`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created and tested Powershell Script on my side with ***Windows Powershell ISE*** and it works 5/5, hope that will work too for you !

---

```
$start_time = Get-Date
$url = "https://www.kingcounty.gov/depts/health/covid-19/data/daily-summary.aspx"
$xlFile = "E:\Test\CovidData.xlsx"
$http_request = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.XMLHTTP
$http_request.open('GET', $url, $false)
#Sending the request
$http_request.send()
$Contents = $http_request.ResponseText
$pattern = "([\w\-\.,@?^=%&/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])(\.ashx)"
$Links = $Contents | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value} | sort -unique
$Filter = $Links -match "data-daily"
$MyUrlFile = "https://www.kingcounty.gov/depts/health/covid-19/data/" + $Filter
$MyUrlFile
Invoke-WebRequest "$MyUrlFile" -Outfile $xlFile
if (Test-Path $xlFile) { Start $xlFile }
Write-Output "Running Script Time taken is : $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Comment: You are a legend. This did exactly what I needed. Now I just need to run it using the Task Scheduler and I'm good to go (Haven't really used that before either so I'm going to mess around with it and if I fail, I'll open a new thread).